# Xcode react-native Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, facebook-login

After updating my RN to 0.18, I have this error that appears when trying to build my project. It comes from this package : http://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login

The error says :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTFBLogin.a(RCTFBLoginManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTFBLogin.a(RCTFBLogin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTFBLogin.a(RCTFBLoginManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I don't really know what it means, if anyone could help me on this one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, found out why. The Facebook SDK frameworks were in my project tree but not added "as" frameworks (they didn't appear in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries").

Comment: can you share a screenshot of what's in your "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"?

Comment: you mean in "Linked Binary with Libraries"? It works also this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, when using 0.40.0+ adding the **-lz** flag to your *Other Linker Flags* within the Project's *Build Settings*, it will allow the linker to correctly reference these from the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I just set up *Other Linker Flags* with

```
-all_load
```